# Selecting percentage of points from multipoint layer (ArcGis)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, lidar, las

I am currently working with las dataset of small area, and I want to run some quick analysis on this area. Since my PC is not the best, I am looking for tool like "extract 50% of multipoints to new layer" so I could run some analysis on this PC. Putting in another way, I am looking for tool which will decrease the density of multipoint layer.

I know I was using something similar in the past, but I can't remember nor find any clues.

It would rapidly decrease the processing time for analysis.

Using ArcMap 10.2.

Comment: Hello,
yep, I am kinda forced to do it in ArcGis, since I dont have access to any other software. But thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [split tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000006000000).  You will need to create a grid over your point dataset and use this grid to split your point dataset into multiple smaller datasets with the split tool.

Comment: I am looking for tool which will decrease the density of multipoint layer.

But I will try it this way also. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

What kind of analysis do you want to do? You could use the LAS to Multipoint GP tool which creates a multipoint feature class and then create a subset from there. Alternatively, you could create a mosaic dataset that points to the LAS data (files or dataset) and this will rasterize the points. The mosaic dataset is designed to perform well with large amounts of data.

Comment: Hey,
thanks for the tips, I was using the LAS to Multipoint thingy and tried to run kriging/idw for comparison and got Out of memory errors.